# Android Studio File inclusion

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I copied a resource file from another project to my project in Android Studio.
Now when I try to edit file it says "**this file do not belong to the project**" and asks if I want to unlock it?
How can I say to Android Studio that this file belongs to project?

Comment: That error message sounds like a source control thing. You should be able to unlock and edit it if you're not using source control; if you are, you should add it to the source control project and check it in.